# Bad connections or bad battery?

Tags: battery

Car battery had gone bad at least in part to corroded terminals.  I cleaned up the terminals and eventually got battery to 12.8.  it had been dropping below 10 volts on startup but with driving/continued charging it also started showing above 10 volts on startup.

Issue is it is dropping below 10 volts on startup again eg 9.66 or 9.86 and cutting out sometimes during driving.

I’m thinking that it’s either the battery or corroded/bad connections etc which maybe causing intermittent performance/charging.

My question is that since we known it went from cutting out frequently to being able to start frequently for some days to cutting out again, would this suggest it’s a connection issue since this implies it’s intermittent or could assuming all else is well, could the faulty battery alone have the same behaviour?  If so how I would imagine it doesnt really get worse then better then worse
Unless it’s a external/charging issue?

Comment: How / where did you measure that on-crank voltage? Multimeter directly on the battery terminals? Or on the cable connectors? Or something else? Is that "on crank" while the starter motor is engaged? How are voltages before and after firing it up?

Comment: @RaphaelP I used a multimeter and saw it drop on start up.  It was directly on terminals not connectors. Every time I start it the charge will go up but then if u put the lights on(2 elimnate surface charge) or wait it goes lower then falls below 10 on startup(at least today it did).  But I think when I checked it in the morning it didn’t drop below 10.  As it is sometimes falls below and other times doesn’t I’m confused if there is some connection somewhere or if it be the battery? cuts out but will start n drive after a few attempts a(thus far) but bad battery should not start consistently?

Comment: @RaphaelP I used a multimeter and saw it drop on start up.  It was directly on terminals not connectors. Every time I start it the charge will go up but then if u put the lights on(2 elimnate surface charge) or wait it goes lower then falls below 10 on startup(at least today it did).  But I think when I checked it in the morning it didn’t drop below 10.  As it is sometimes falls below and other times doesn’t I’m confused if there is some connection somewhere or if it be the battery? cuts out but will start n drive after a few attempts a(thus far) but bad battery should not start consistently?